# I want to show pagination on Category Page using hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-6

My Category page is showing websites submitted in specific category using hasManyThrough Relation.
I want to paginate results on category page. How can i use paginate in my controller?

Category Model

```
    class Category extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
    
        protected $fillable = ['name','category_id'];
        
        public function subcategories()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
        }
    
        public function websites()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(Website::class, Subcategory::class);
        }
    
    }
```

Controller

````
    public function show(Category $category)
        {
            return view('category',compact('category'));
        }
     ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
public function show(Category $category){
  return view('category')
     ->with('category', $category)
     ->with('websites', $category->websites()->paginate(10))
     ->with('subcategories', $category->subcategories);
}
```

Comment: @AadeeShah you have to call `{{$websites->links()}}`

Comment: also consider that this works only if it's the only pagination you have on this page